# JavaScript: "New Audio()" not working on mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, audio

http://codepen.io/abdulahhamzic/pen/GjKAAb This is the project I'm working on.

I am using Angular JS for the project and this is how I declared the variable for the audio in the Angular controller:

```
var audio = new Audio('http://www.brainwave-music.com/fileadmin/media/Alpha-Brainwave-Relax-Meditation-Ambient.mp3')
```

Then, I play the audio in a function, which is called on button click:

```
$scope.play = function () {
    if (!playDisabled) {

        ....

        if (checkbox.checked) {
            audio.play();
            audio.loop();
        }
    }
};
```

This works very well in any desktop browser, but how do I make the audio work on mobile devices too? (I used Samsung Galaxy S I9000 (Android 5.1.1) to test it).

Comment: The example you provided works on my Sony Xperia Z5 (Android 6.0.1, Build number: 32.2.A.0.253, Chrome version: 52.0.2743.98)
It also works on my iPad Air (MD785HC/A), iOS version: 9.3.5 (13G36), both in Chrome (52.0.2743.84) and Safari.